# Integrating with legacy db in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

`models.py` was created from legacy database.i have created a `models.py`  and created `admin.py` for app `interface` and the app name in `installed app` ,i have around 76 tables (`76 classes in models.py`).

admin.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python  
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.db import models  
from interface.models import Students,ApplyLeaves  
site.register(ApplyLeaves)  
site.register(Students)  
for m in get_models(db):  
       site.register(m)
```

In above case Students and ApplyLeaves classes are not getting registerd in admin interface.

I have placed `admin.py`in app directory as well as project directory,still app is not getting registered for administration

Comment: how did you edit the code?mean keyword highlighting etc...

Comment: Are you sure the tables for Students and ApplyLeaves are on the database that you are using?

Comment: in db table name are =>students,apply_leaves in models.py they are =>Students,ApplyLeaves

Comment: What else have you tried? Could you paste models.py and admin.py here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to register all models into django admin, you should (although you dont *have to*) create an *instance of the admin*.

This is because, although django admin can expose all models based just on the schema alone, it has so many bells and whistels to make that schema representation *meaningful real solution*.

That said, in your case, *you should not* keep this `admin.py` in project level, but just at the application level. Is the `Students` and `ApplyLeaves` in the same `db` database you have passed to the `get_models`?

The elegant solution to what you are going to do would be as follows:

`project-folder/bare_tables.py`

```
from django.db.models import get_models
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite, ModelAdmin

class BareTables(AdminSite):
    pass

new_admin = BareTables(name='bare_tables')

for el in get_models():
    new_admin.register(el,ModelAdmin)
```

In your `urls.py`

```
 from bare_tables import new_admin

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^bare-tables/', include(new_admin.urls)),
     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

That way you can continue to build *meaningful interfaces* in `/admin` while you have all tables exposed in `/bare-tables`.

Comment: Students and ApplyLeaves are in same db,your solution din work

Answer (score 0):

@gladysbixy
`models.py`
{
`
        from django.db import models

```
class AdditionalExamGroups(models.Model):  
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    batch_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    exam_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)   
    is_published = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    result_published = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    students_list = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    exam_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)    

    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'additional_exam_groups'  

class AdditionalExamScores(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    student_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    additional_exam_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    marks = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True)  
    grading_level_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    is_failed = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)    
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'additional_exam_scores'  

class AdditionalExams(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    additional_exam_group_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    subject_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    maximum_marks = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    minimum_marks = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    grading_level_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    weightage = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    event_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'additional_exams'  

 class AdditionalFields(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
       db_table = u'additional_fields'  

class ApplyLeaves(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    employee_leave_types_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    is_half_day = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    approved = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    viewed_by_manager = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    manager_remark = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'apply_leaves'  

 class ArchivedEmployeeAdditionalDetails(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    additional_field_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'archived_employee_additional_details'  

 class ArchivedEmployeeBankDetails(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    bank_field_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    bank_info = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'archived_employee_bank_details'  




class Students(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    admission_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    class_roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    admission_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    batch_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    birth_place = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    nationality_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    student_category_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    country_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    immediate_contact_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    is_sms_enabled = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    photo_filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    photo_content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    photo_data = models.TextField(blank=True)  
    status_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    is_active = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    is_deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)   
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = u'students'  


class Users(models.Model):  
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    admin = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    student = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    employee = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  
    hashed_password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    reset_password_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    reset_password_code_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
     class Meta:  
         db_table = u'users'
```

}`
I have skipped lots of tables cos bored to indent...

`admin.py' you can find in previous post